# Modify nginx base image with a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, dockerfile, exec

On my virtual machine, i created this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install nginx
COPY content/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

because i want to alter the nginx base image to my own by starting off with replacing the html file.

When the container is ran and everything's working fine i still see the default nginx html file when i go to the ip address, even though when i use `docker exec` commands and go inside the container i can see that my html file is indeed copied but the changes are not reflected.

what could be the issue?

Comment: How are you running the container?  When you say "changes are not reflected", what do you mean?  (Do you rebuild the image and recreate the container after changing your HTML?)  You can run the `COPY` command you show against the prebuilt `nginx` image and that may be a simpler setup.

Comment: I just exit out of the container after making the modification (which to my understanding is not enough) so i use docker exec to restart nginx from within the container after I change something, and it still doesn't work.

I actually now have figured out the issue and it's resolved, but if you could please expand on your suggested solution of running `COPY` command ...

Comment: I usually consider `docker exec` as more of a debugging tool.  Any change you make in that shell will be lost as soon as the container is deleted, and deleting and recreating a container is a very normal operation if any aspect of the container configuration changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For NGINX installed on Ubuntu the default NGINX welcome page is actually not found at `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html` but at `/var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html`.

Update your  `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install nginx

COPY content/index.html /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Test contents for `content/index.html`:

```
Hello, World!
```

Build and run.

```bash
docker build -t nginx-test . && docker run -it -p 80:80 nginx-test
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have actually figured it out on my own while I was browsing through the container